# Sequential scan for column indexed with varchar_pattern_ops

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, database-design, pattern-matching

I have a table Users and it contains location column. I have indexed location column using varchar_pattern_ops. But when I run query planner it tells me it is doing a sequential scan.

```
EXPLAIN ANALAYZE
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE lower(location) like '%nepa%'
ORDER BY location desc;
```

It gives following result:

```
Sort  (cost=12.41..12.42 rows=1 width=451) (actual time=0.084..0.087 rows=8 loops=1)
Sort Key: location
Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
  ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..12.40 rows=1 width=451) (actual time=0.029..0.051 rows=8 loops=1)
      Filter: (lower((location)::text) ~~ '%nepa%'::text)
 Planning time: 0.211 ms
 Execution time: 0.147 ms
```

I have searched through stackoverflow. Found most answers to be like "postgres performs sequential scan in large table in case index scan will be slower". But my table is not big either.

The index in my `users` table is:

```
"index_users_on_lower_location_varchar_pattern_ops" btree (lower(location::text) varchar_pattern_ops)
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`*_patter_ops` indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html) are good for ***prefix matching*** - `LIKE` patterns anchored to the start, without leading wildcard. But not for your predicate:

```
WHERE lower(location) like '%nepa%'
```

I suggest a **trigram index** instead. You don't need `lower()` in the index (or query) since trigram indexes support case insensitive `ILIKE` (or `~*`) at practically the same cost.

Follow instructions here:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

Also:

> But my table is not big either.

You seem to have that *backwards*. If your table is *not* big enough, it's faster for Postgres to just read it sequentially and not bother with indexes. You would not create any indexes at all. The tipping point depends on many factors.

Your index definition does not make sense to begin with:

```
(lower(location::text) varchar_pattern_ops)
```

For a `varchar` columns use the `varchar_pattern_ops` operator class.
But `lower()` returns `text` even for `varchar` input, so use `text_pattern_ops`. Except that you probably do not need this (or any?) index at all, as advised.
And if you still think you need that index, consider a `COLLATE "C"` index instead. See:

- [Is there a difference between text_pattern_ops and COLLATE "C"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/291250/3684)

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. I will definitely do that. You made me clear pattern_ops are used for prefix matching. I did not understand that before. Also, I will use varchar for location field.  You are a hero.